# What are some examples of good questions falling under the tags (soft-question), (advice), (career-development)?

Tags: discussion, tagging, allowed-questions, soft-question

What are some examples of good questions falling under the following tags?

- [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question)
- [advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice)
- [career-development](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development)

I am asking this question because often, positive reactions from users towards certain off-topic questions allow these questions to get by. Hence, I guess that highly up voted questions are not necessarily good examples.

Comment: In my opinion "advice" is utterly useless as a tag.  On MO I campaign for its deletion. I did not realize it exists here too. I think will do the same here. To make clear what my point is: it can mean most everything, it's usage is quite arbitrary.

Comment: @quid on top of  that, it may be fooling people into thinking personal advice questions are ok just when we've started deliberately discouraging those here . I'm behind you on getting rid of advice.

Comment: And any question on career development should really go to academia.se, I would guess. Soft-question has its uses, but I don't trust myself to explain it well at this time of night.

Comment: Maybe we should do the same for _all_ tags....

Comment: The tag career-development is mostly garbage. [It has the record for the most closed question with 60%.](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/282074/tags-with-most-closed-question-percentage) It distantly leads [tag:publishing] which has 25% of its question closed. [tag:advice] is at 21%, [tag:soft-question] "only" at 11% (recall that only 3.9% of all questions are closed). At least for advice and career-developme,t, I believe you're asking for something that doesn't exist.

Comment: Perhaps these soft questions aren't so bad (or have prompted useful answers): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71874/can-i-use-my-powers-for-good, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/733754/visually-stunning-math-concepts-which-are-easy-to-explain, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154/do-complex-numbers-really-exist, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250/a-challenge-by-r-p-feynman-give-counter-intuitive-theorems-that-can-be-transl, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820686/obvious-theorems-that-are-actually-false, for a start.

Comment: @GerryMyerson the first is bad as it contains a lot of fluff about "good" that is a distraction.

Comment: While not a law (because there are exceptions), a guideline for if a tag is good or not is "Can someone be an expert in ___?" And while there are plenty of radio show hosts who claim to be experts in advice, they're hardly what I would consider objective. If someone put the advice tag on my SE I'd burninate it faster than... a ... thing that goes really fast or something.

Answer (score 4):

The following two questions seem like good questions to me tagged [career-development](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/career-development)

[Research Experience for Undergraduates: Summer Programs (that accept non-American applicants)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/16254/research-experience-for-undergraduates-summer-programs-that-accept-non-america)

[Pure mathematics in our society](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855092/pure-mathematics-in-our-society)

They are both specific to mathematics and admit factual answers that are generally applicable.

There should be some good questions that happen to be tagged [advice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/advice), but I feel this tag is so vague and broad that "under the [...] tag" just is not applicable.

Likewise, the tag [soft-question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/soft-question) is in my opinion too broad to talk in a meaningful way about questions "under the [...] tag". In some sense it is an "anti-tag;" historically, a main reason for it to exist is so that users that so wish can block vague and non-mathematical questions (at least it was like this on MO and a lot of the early tagging conventions here where imported from there).